# Calculating closest point in Golang

Tags: go, geolocation, geo

I am [writing a lambda function](https://github.com/kaihendry/geoclose) that needs to return the closest point to another. I'm thinking that there must be a better way than calculating the distance to [all 5000 points](https://github.com/kaihendry/geoclose/blob/master/all.json) that I have every time.

```
func (places Places) closest(w place) (c place) {
    c = places[0]
    closestSoFar := w.Point.GreatCircleDistance(c.Point)
    for _, p := range places[1:] {
        distance := w.Point.GreatCircleDistance(p.Point)
        if distance < closestSoFar {
            // Set the return
            c = p
            // Record closest distance
            closestSoFar = distance
        }
    }
    return
}
```

If you could review the code and point to libraries I should be using, I would be most grateful. Also I'd like to benchmark different approaches so I am wondering how to define that. I think currently my approach takes ~0.025s on my i7 system. Perhaps what I am doing here is premature optimization? Since my bus stop data probably won't exceed 10k points.

Comment: Looking for libraries is offtopic on SO. For the optimisation: Precompute and save the nearest neighbour/distance

Answer (score 2):

You can split the whole plane into grids that can be decided by an O(1) operation of the points' latitude and longitude, like `(int(lat) / 10, int(lng) /10)`. Precalculate for each of the 5000 points and each grids of what the max and min distance is between the grid and the point. Maintain for each grid a set of points that can possibly produce the minimum distance. With a good dividing algorithms (usually just divide latitude and longitude with a certain number is good enough), the set should be very small, like no more than 10 points.

So when you get a query, you can get the grid the point is in immediately and has a small list of points that can be the closet. Simply loop over it and find the one.

Calculating the min and max distance is trivial, just be careful with some special cases. Maintaining the set can be done by keeping a current (min,max): when a new pair of (minI,maxI) is calculated, compare it to current ones. If maxI < min, discard everything we had and use the new pair.
If minI > max, nothing happens. Else, just add the new pair and update min/max accordingly.

I am currently on mobile so I can't provide code. If you need code to see how it is done, I would add it later.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in the code or even better.. some existing library function